# How to compress the file(such as pdf) in client side before upload using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to compress a file (such as pdf) in client side before upload using jquery?

I don't get any best idea or answer about this question from previous solutions.

Comment: Compress how? I mean do you have an algorithm you want to create or are you asking about a known compression format (like Zip) [for JavaScript](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+compression+library)?

Answer (score 0):

This library can probably help https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [gzip-js](https://github.com/beatgammit/gzip-js)

> The main goal of this project is to bring GZIP compression to the browser.

But if you use this, you also should decompress gzipped file on server-side.